# BitmapData with Scale9Grid

Tags: apache-flex, bitmapdata, skin, bitmapimage, scale9grid

I have a Skin for SkinnableContainer.
Skin contains only the original contentGroup and s:BitmapImage as background.
Background image stretchers out according to width and height content.
The used image is .png with transparent regions.

To create hitarea, I used this algorithm:
http://www.webverwirklichung.com/en/blog/programming/flex/creating-hitarea-png-image-transparent-alpha-regions-flex

Everything's working fine until I start to stretch the SkinnableContainer (along with the image in the skin).
I have a scale9Grid for the image.

The problem is, that when stretching the image, the bitmapData of the image is still the same (same width and height). Therefore I need to somehow obtain the bitmapData of the image for the scale9Grid application.

The background of the component is an image, which has some transparent areas. It is only possible to click on the visible part of the image. The image will stretch according to the content in contentGroup.

Need an advice, please.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the `BitmapData.draw()` method?

After the container is resized and the 9 slice scaling has been applied (or whatever the appropriate trigger is) do:

```
var b:BitmapData = new BitmapData(container.width, container.height);
b.draw(container);
```

Then use this new bitmap with the algorithm that creates the hit area.